# abrir modal com link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal

bom, eu nunca fiz e ja procurei em bastantes sites e nao encontro nada que faça o que eu preciso.
Eu preciso de fazer apareceer uma modal apartir de um link_to, a pessoa quando clica no link_to abre o modal, obrigado.

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152486/how-to-add-bootstrap-modal-with-link-to-so-the-link-content-open-in-modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a melhor opção é usar o bootstrap, dê uma olhada neste artigo:http://www.devmedia.com.br/bootstrap-modal-como-utilizar-em-seus-projetos/37426

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei esta solução hoje a partir idem de uma necessidade minha e funcionou.

Resposta de Boris Bresciani.

```
<%= link_to 'Click Here', '#myModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando Rails 7

```
<%= link_to 'Add user', '#',  {:remote => true, 'data-bs-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-bs-target' => '#exampleModal', class: 'nav-link'}  %>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).